# PHPCodeSniffer - blank lines before function

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I'm using PHP CodeSniffer, and one of the rules specifies that there must be a blank line for each function (CodeStandard.WhiteSpace.FunctionSpacing.Before)

Whilst this works fine, it also includes the first function at the top of the class. I would like to exclude this Error from being included in these circumstances.

I know how to override rules and create custom rulesets, but no idea how to amend the CodeStandard.WhiteSpace.FunctionSpacing.Before so that it excludes the first function .

Comment: You need to modify the PHP source where that sniff is defined, probably something like CodeStandard/Sniffs/WhiteSpace/FunctionSpacing/BeforeSniff.php. That said, this sniff is not one of the standards included with PHPCS -- it appears to be a local custom sniff, so I doubt you'll be able to get any help with it. Alternatively, check out the sniff Squiz.WhiteSpace.FunctionSpacing -- I think it already does what you're looking for.

Comment: Just follow the advice and put a newline there. I never understood why some guys don't do that. IMHO this is a poor coding style.

Answer (score 0):

**In [PHP-CS-Fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer) there is "method_separation" fixer** for that:

*Methods must be separated with one blank line.*

It also takes care of not only methods, but functions and properties as well.

If you want to use PHP_CodeSniffer, you can combine them easily with tool I wrote - [EasyCodingStandard](https://github.com/symplify/easy-coding-standard).

Comment: Maybe add a disclaimer that you built that EasyCodingStandard library?

Comment: @halfpastfour.am Sure!